# How to run asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to run asp.net application with encrypted web.config ,is it possible 
note that ASP.NET application have a database with encrypted connectionstring and a "cannot read connection string " message is generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you should encrypt the web.config *after* deployment, not before.

The encryption with aspnet_regiis uses the target machine's Keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows DPAPI encryption.  [Here's a MS patterns and practices article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) that walks you through step by step.